# even number scanner code

Tags: java.util.scanner

i am creating a scanner test.  I have managed to print even number 1-50. i want to do a scanner code so that when a user inputs i.e 8 it will print all the even number from 8-50.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModulusCalculation
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int endLimit = 50;

    System.out.println("WE ARE GOING TO PRINT EVEN NUMBER FROM 1 AND " + endLimit);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    for (int startingPoint = 1; startingPoint <= endLimit; startingPoint++)
    {
        if (startingPoint % 2 == 0)
        {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(+startingPoint);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: well i am trying to make it work like that at the moment its will only print on return all the values from 1-50/ no need to be rude genuine and trying to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont need to read  **input.nextLine();** within the for loop.

**STEP 1:** read a starting integer value

**STEP 2:** for (int startingPoint = startinteger; startingPoint <= endLimit; startingPoint++)

**STEP3:** print all the even numbers based on the condition within the for loop